# I need UnSupportedOperationException in C++

Tags: c++, exception, stl

I need an exception like UnSupportedOperationException in C++ but can't find one. I was hoping it will be in STL but seemingly its not there.Should I create one myself by deriving from STL exception class?

Why I need it?: I am implementing composite design pattern which requires throwing unsupportoperationexception in bases class. Jave has it but c++ don't.

Comment: Did you search for it? http://www.elcel.com/docs/opentop/API/ot/UnsupportedOperationException.html

Comment: Here: `throw UnSupportedOperationException;`. Hope you `catch` it.

Comment: See Federico's answer if you don't have a sense of humor. And Daniel's too. Either way, we have no clue what exactly you need, it could be as trivial as writing `class UnSupportedOperationException {};` or actually figuring out what your real problem is.

Comment: I guess -1 is for the 'sense of anger' :) I did say why I need it, read the OP.

Comment: Why does it need to have that name? The standard C++ libraries have a set of predefined exceptions that you can use, named by category. Either use them directly, or if you think they are useful, inherit your own exception class from the one that makes more sense; for your scenario I would go with `std::logic_error`.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you should avoid to create exception classes. Use the class which matches your case best, e.g.

```
throw std::runtime_error( "foo() is unsupported" );
```

Only if you want to catch an exception and you know how to handle the situation, you need to derive your own class. In that case, derive from the standard library's exception class which best matches your case. Check the [exception categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error) offered.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should explain what do you expect "UnSupportedOperationException" to do in particular.

Anyway, if something is not in default libraries you should use an extern one or create it by yourself.

In this case the easiest way is the one you said.